# Round integer to nearest high number in array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array of ints like this: [32,128,1024,2048,4096]

Given a specific value, I need to get the closest value in the array that is equal to, or higher than, the value.

I have the following code

```
  private int GetNextValidSize(int size, int[] validSizes)
  {

      int returnValue = size;

      for (int i = 0; i < validSizes.Length; i++)
      {
          if (validSizes[i] >= size)
          {
              returnValue = validSizes[i];
              break;
          }
      }

      return returnValue;
  }
```

It works, but is there any better/faster way to do it? The array will never contain more than 5-10 elements.

**Clarification:** I actually want to return the original value/size if it is bigger than any of the valid sizes. The validSizes array can be considered to always be sorted, and it will always contain at least one value.

Comment: will your array elements always be powers of 2? => if yes some kind of bit magic might be the fastest sollution

Comment: One potential problem with this code is that the function does not in any way indicate if the value returned even exists in the array (so if size > the highest value in validSizes, then GetNextValidSize returns size, which is actually invalid).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given that you have only 5-10 elements I would consider this to be ok.

Comment: +1. You may find a faster way but it won't be better in terms of understanding.

Comment: +1 ... and probably not even faster. Asymptotically faster algorithms usually display a higher constant. If your array is limited to 10 elements you can just assume that it is a constant time operation where the constant is 10 compare operations, which is not that much of a constant anyway (if you use a balanced tree you will end up with a four level tree, making for at most 4 comparisons that is not that much of an advantage...

Answer (score 8):

With only 5-10 elements, definitely go with the simplest solution. Getting a binary chop working would help with a larger array, but it's got at least the *potential* for off-by-one errors.

Rather than breaking, however, I would return directly from the loop to make it even simpler, and use foreach as well:

```
  private int GetNextValidSize(int size, int[] validSizes)
  {    
      int returnValue = size;

      foreach (int validSize in validSizes)
      {
          if (validSize >= size)
          {
              return validSizes;
          }
      }

      // Nothing valid    
      return size;
  }
```

You can make this even simpler with LINQ:

```
// Make sure we return "size" if none of the valid sizes are greater
return validSizes.Concat(new[] { size })
                 .First(validSize => validSize >= size);
```

It would be even simpler without the `Concat` step... or if there were a `Concat` method that just took a single element. That's easy to write, admittedly:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Concat(this IEnumerable<T> source,
                                    T tail)
{
    foreach (T element in source)
    {
        yield return element;
    }
    yield return tail;
}
```

then it's just:

```
return validSizes.Concat(size).First(validSize => validSize >= size);
```

Alternatively (and I realise I'm presenting way more options than are really needed here!) an overload for `FirstOrDefault` which took the default value to return:

```
public static T FirstOrDefault(this IEnumerable<T> source,
                               Func<T, bool> predicate,
                               T defaultValue)
{
    foreach (T element in source)
    {
        if (predicate(element))
        {
            return element;
        }
    }
    return defaultValue;
}
```

Call it like this:

```
return validSizes.FirstOrDefault(validSize => validSize >= size, size);
```

Both of these are overkill for a single use, but if you're already building up a library of extra LINQ operators, it could be useful.

Answer (score 2):

```
int[] validSizes = new int[] { 32, 128, 1024, 2048, 4096 };

int sizeICareAbout = 4096;

Console.Write(validSizes.Max(i => i < sizeICareAbout ? i : Int32.MinValue));
```

This will return Int32.MinValue if you put in the smallest value.  God, I love LINQ.

Answer (score 2):

You could use LINQ to simplify the query - it will probably be as fast as anything you could write if your list is sorted.

```
int someInitialValue;
int defaultIfNotFound = ... // set to some value, even initialValue
// attempt to find first value less than or equal
int bestMatch = myListOfValues.Concat( new []{defaultIfNotFound} )
                              .FirstOrDefault( x => x >= someInitialValue );
```

If the array is not ordered, or if you need better performance:

```
myListOfValues.OrderBy( x => x ).Concat( new []{defaultIfNotFound} )
                                .FirstOrDefault( x => x >= someInitialValue );
```

You mention that you list is relatively small (5-10 items) - so linear search is probably fast enough. However, on a larger list (dozens or hundreds of items), you may want to consider [using a binary search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cy9f6wb.aspx) to find the value:

```
// index is positive if an exact match is found
// if no exact match is found, the index returned will be two's complement and
// reference the next number immediately larger than the search target
int index = myListOfValues.BinarySearch( someInitialValue );
if( index < 0 && ~index > myListOfValues.Length )
   bestMatch = someInitialValue;
else
   bestMatch = index < 0 ? myListOfValues[~index] : myListOfValues[index];
```

Comment: You need to consider the case where the initial value is higher than anything in the array. That makes it uglier (see my answer).

Comment: True, however, the caller didn't define the expected outcome for that case. I will update my answer to account for that.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work. Here are 3 test cases where it fails. In fact, the function interface doesn't have any return result for failure.

I wrote a corrected version, GetNextValidSize2. Since there is no way to return a failure message, I throw an exception for those cases. Here are the results of the run:

test1 : GetNextValidSize failed
test1 : GetNextValidSize2 passed
test2 : GetNextValidSize Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
test2 : GetNextValidSize2 validSizes is nothing
test3 : GetNextValidSize passed
test3 : GetNextValidSize2 No items in validSizes

By the way, LINQ may be simpler or easier, but it can hardly be more efficient. It can probably be equally efficient if the query optimizer/CLR optimizer work well.

Here's the code - it's in VB since that's what I'm using at the moment, don't want to switch mental gears:

Module Module1

```
''' <summary>
''' Error - does not work if validSizes is Nothing, or has 0 elements, or if
''' the list contains a validSize that is not the closest one before a closer one,
''' or there are no valid sizes.
''' </summary>
Public Function GetNextValidSize(ByVal size As Integer, ByVal validSizes As List(Of Integer)) As Integer
    Dim returnValue As Integer = size

    For i As Integer = 0 To validSizes.Count - 1 Step 1
        If validSizes.Item(i) >= size Then
            returnValue = validSizes.Item(i)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Return returnValue
End Function

''' <summary>
''' Returns the closest item in validSizes that is >= size. Throws an exception if one cannot 
''' be found.
''' </summary>
 Public Function GetNextValidSize2(ByVal size As Integer, ByVal validSizes As List(Of Integer)) As Integer
    Dim closestValue As Integer = Integer.MaxValue
    Dim found As Boolean = False

    If validSizes Is Nothing Then
        Throw New Exception("validSizes is nothing")
    End If

    If validSizes.Count = 0 Then
        Throw New Exception("No items in validSizes")
    End If

    For Each x In validSizes
        If x >= size Then
            found = True
            If x < closestValue Then
                closestValue = x
            End If
        End If
    Next
    If Not found Then
        Throw New Exception("No items found")
    End If
    Return closestValue
End Function

''' <summary>
''' Output the result of a test.
''' </summary>
 Public Sub outputResult(ByVal testName As String, ByVal result As Boolean, ByVal funcName As String)
    Dim passFail As String
    If result Then
        passFail = " passed"
    Else
        passFail = " failed"
    End If
    Console.WriteLine(testName & " : " & funcName & passFail)
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Output the result of a test where an exception occurred.
''' </summary>
 Public Sub outputResult(ByVal testName As String, ByVal ex As Exception, ByVal funcName As String)

    Console.WriteLine(testName & " : " & funcName & " " & ex.Message())
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Test with a list of 3 integers
''' </summary>
 Public Sub test1()
    Dim aList As New List(Of Integer)
    aList.Add(5)
    aList.Add(4)
    aList.Add(3)
    Dim result = GetNextValidSize(3, aList)
    outputResult("test1", 3 = GetNextValidSize(3, aList), "GetNextValidSize")
    outputResult("test1", 3 = GetNextValidSize2(3, aList), "GetNextValidSize2")
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Test with a null reference
''' </summary>
Public Sub test2()
    Dim aList = Nothing
    Try
        outputResult("test2", GetNextValidSize(3, aList), "GetNextValidSize")
    Catch ex As Exception
        outputResult("test2", ex, "GetNextValidSize")
    End Try
    Try
        outputResult("test2", GetNextValidSize2(3, aList), "GetNextValidSize2")
    Catch ex As Exception
        outputResult("test2", ex, "GetNextValidSize2")
    End Try
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Test with an empty array.
''' </summary>
Public Sub test3()
    Dim aList As New List(Of Integer)
    Try
        outputResult("test3", GetNextValidSize(3, aList), "GetNextValidSize")
    Catch ex As Exception
        outputResult("test3", ex, "GetNextValidSize")
    End Try
    Try
        outputResult("test3", GetNextValidSize2(3, aList), "GetNextValidSize2")
    Catch ex As Exception
        outputResult("test3", ex, "GetNextValidSize2")
    End Try
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Run all tests.
''' </summary>
Public Sub testAll()
    test1()
    test2()
    test3()
End Sub

Sub Main()
    testAll()
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

End Module

Answer (score 1):

If your array is ordered, you can fast this up by using a binary search algorithm.

See there: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

Answer (score -1):

I think you will just get the *first* greater number, not necessarily the *closest greater* number.

If your array isn't sorted, you'll need to double-pass it to find the right number. First you'll find the greatest, and second the smaller value that is still greater than the original value.

Comment: You don't need two passes. A single pass over all elements keeping the current best guess is all that's needed for an unsorted array.

Comment: Yes, I missed it broadly! <coding horror>

Comment: doesn't specify whether the array is guaranteed to be sorted or not. If sorted, then the first will be the closest greatest. If not, then binary search won't work.