# Rounding to the closest number in a given array of numbers

Tags: c#, rounding

Before posting this I looked at both of these answers:

[C# Finding Nearest Number in Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120944/c-sharp-finding-nearest-number-in-array)

[Round integer to nearest high number in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143451/round-integer-to-nearest-high-number-in-array)

While the first was somewhat helpful with regard to the extension method mentioned in one of the answers, I was not able to understand it to the depth that would allow me to modify and implement it to suit my specific circumstance, and the second wasn't suitable to my needs due to its array being of a short length and if I was to use an array to store all the base 2 numbers up to 268 million, it would have a relatively large number of entries.

Basically what I'm trying to do here is take RoundedSpeed (Which has been rounded up to an integer using `Math.Round`) and round it to the closest number (it must never round down, only up) that is the result of a power being applied to 2. (Example numbers include 16384, 32768, 65536, 131072, etc)

For this particular example, the number that I would want to round to is 32768. (Though other methods may want another number, but that is an issue for me to deal with and is out of the scope of this example).

Here's the code I have right now:

```
double Speed = Math.Pow(2, ((-900 + Time) / -60)) - 1;
double RoundedSpeed = Math.Round(Speed);
```

Originally I was looking at using an array to store the relevant numbers to round to, but is there any other way I could round up `RoundedSpeed` to the nearest base 2 integer?

Comment: For anyone that would suggest using LINQ, I have not learned LINQ yet, so please avoid using LINQ in the answer unless absolutely necessary. Some simple loops may not be the most elegant solution, but honestly, I'm not worried about code elegance, I just want something that I can come back to later and understand what it's doing.

Comment: you want to round a number up to the nearest power of 2 - correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var x = 56;
var y = (int)Math.Pow(2.0, Math.Ceiling(Math.Log(x, 2.0)));
```

Results in 64 in this case.

Effectively this is determining for `n` what `2 ^ n = x`, but since `n` is probably a fractional amount it uses `Ceiling` to bring this number up to the nearest integer (or leave it if it is already an integer). So `n2 = Ceiling(n)`. Then it simple computes `2 ^ n2` to get the result of `y`.

Comment: ++ You beat me to it. Much more elegant and simple solution.

Comment: Very elegant, and quite clever. But maybe OP would benefit from an explanation as to why this works

Comment: ^ Agreed with that. I'm not entirely sure why this works xD Though something tells me it's got to do with the log law of a^(Loga(x)) = x.

I will test this in my formula and see what it spits out.



Also, why the var? Do we not explicitly know the data type of this?

Comment: @Enigmativity This actually works, kudos to you man, absolute legend. I'll mark this as the accepted answer once the explanation on why this works is posted.

Comment: @LC14199 I don't think explanation of log2 and 2^n are reasonable for SO... You may want to clarify what part of that statement (short of basic math) need an explanation.

Comment: @LC14199 - I've added an explanation.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a loop:

```
double RoundedSpeed = Math.Round(Speed);
int maxAllowed = 100; // prevent infinite loop
for (int i=1; i < maxAllowed; i++)
{
    double number = Math.Pow(2.0, (double)i);
    if (number > RoundedSpeed)
        return number;
}
```

If you aren't in a method that returns something, then instead of return number, do something useful with number and then add "break;" to stop the loop.

You'll want to add error handling to make sure you don't overflow the maximum integer value, and to do something useful if you don't find a number by the time you get to maxAllowed.  There may be better solutions, but this is an "easy" solution...

Comment: Yours works well, but @Enigmativity's solution is simpler, elegant and better. IMMHO!

Comment: I'd argue calculating log 2 would be much slower, but I don't know if the compiler performs optimisations when you feed it into a ceiling like that :P

Answer (score 3):

You can do this very efficiently with bitwise operations.  I've used `ulong` for input and output here.  This will run very quickly.

```
ulong FancyRound(ulong value) {
    value -= 1;
    value |= value >> 1;
    value |= value >> 2;
    value |= value >> 4;
    value |= value >> 8;
    value |= value >> 16;
    value |= value >> 32;
    return value + 1;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
for (ulong i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", i, FancyRound(i));
}
```

Output:

```
1: 1
2: 2
3: 4
4: 4
5: 8
6: 8
7: 8
8: 8
9: 16
```

It works by "cascading" all the set bits down so that after all the `|` are complete, all the low bits will be set, up to the most significant set bit.  After that, the result is incremented to get a round power of 2.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this, I haven't benchmarked it so I won't make any claims about speed:

```
    long input = 32111;
    long powerTwo = 1;
    int count = 0;
    int maxCount = 63; //You can't return 2^64 in a long so 63 should be the max here, as we start at 2^0!
    while (input > powerTwo && count < maxCount) {
        count++;
        powerTwo <<= 1;
    }
    return powerTwo;
```

Outputs 32,768, it works because a long (or at least the lower half) is represented in memory as 000000001 (which is 1) and the `<<=` operation simply shifts the bits left 1 and assigns the result to `powerTwo` so it becomes 000000010 (which is 2) for the next iteration, then it just plonks out the value it got to when it was bigger than the `input`.

If you know it's going to terminate prior to overflowing a long then you can remove the count stuff.